# C Code of hell : quick sort program running to infinite loop : weird situation

Tags: c, quicksort

I have written a C code for Quicksort which seems perfectly OK.
But the code doesn't works perfectly and gets weirdly into infinte loop or something else(which I don't know) while taking values from array, and does nothing after that loop which takes values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int flag=0;
int partition(int *,int,int);
void quicksort(int *A,int low, int high)          //Code for quicksort function
{
    int pivot;
    printf("%d",flag);
    flag++;
    if(low<high)
    {
     pivot =partition(A,low,high);        //calls partition function
     quicksort(A,low,pivot);
     quicksort(A,pivot,high);
    }
}
//code for partition function
int partition(int *A,int low,int high)
{
    int pivot,left,right,temp;
    pivot=A[low];
    left=low;
    right=high;
    printf("%d",flag);
    flag++;
    while(left<right)
        {
         while(A[left]<pivot)
            left++;
         while(A[right]>pivot)
            right++;
         if(left<right)
            {
             temp=A[left];
             A[left]=A[right];
             A[right]=temp;
            }
        }
    temp=A[right];
    A[right]=A[left];
    A[left]=temp;
    return right;
}

int main()
    {
        int a[10],i,n;
        printf("\n***QUICK SORT***");
        printf("\nENTER THE NUMBERS OF ENTRIES:");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        printf("\nENTER THE ENTRTIES IN ARRAY:");
        //PROBLEM IS IN THIS LOOP OR ELSE (I DONT KNOW WHAT EXACTLY WHAT THE PROBLEM IS)

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("i=%d\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);     
        }
        //IF WE COMMENT THIS BELOW LINE OF FUNCTION CALL THEN LOOP WORKS FINE
        quicksort(a,0,n-1);    //passes the array and first and last element

        printf("\nTHE SORTED ARRAY IS:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf(" %d \n ",a[i]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "I DONT KNOW WHAT EXACTLY WHAT THE PROBLEM IS" (Unless you use an Apple-II, of course): 1st: DO NOT SCREAM! 2) Then find out using a debugger.

Comment: defining `a[10]` and then asking for user to input the size....inviting the trouble....

Comment: If the problem disappears when you comment out the call to `quicksort()`, then the problem probably is in the `quicksort()` function, not in the preceeding loop. You could use a debugger to break program execution and find out what it's doing when it seems to get stuck.

Comment: Your `partition()` function is your offender, make sure your logic is correct in there.

Comment: @bentank - I concur, the fact that the `pivot` is in the lowest element of the Array, that none of the local variables are instantiated, and that it seems in the last few lines another swap is performed after a swap had already taken place leads to believe that is where the error is.

@Nikhil Pandit - You may want to format your code alittle more to help with your debugging process. If you think this is "C coding hell" just wait and see...

Comment: the code would be much more readable (and understandable) if code blocks were separated by a blank line

Comment: this line: '**//code for partition function**' is not a valid comment.  Suggest: '//**code for partition function**'.   Notice the comment start sequence '//' is before the beginning of the comment rather than buried within the comment.

Comment: logic is correct.
OK I agree the size of array is small written over here but I also tried the same thing with a[100] and also with a controlled loop of 10 numbers( i.e taking 10 instead of "n" in the loop)
also tried to debug, but there is nothing particularly found at which I could point out,
You may say If you comment the quicksort function call then the problem goes away than the problem is in that function but than a question arise that if I remove the double slash than the program is not even calling that function, and the worse thing is, it gets suck somewhere in between loop and CALL.

Comment: hey user3629249 I am not running the code using those comments in the program, Obviously the compiler wil through an error for such comments , those are just written in the editor over here for info only. :-p

Comment: please indent consistently.  please use meaningful comments.  I.E. 'calls partition function' is NOT a meaningful comment.   That info was obvious from the code statement and was meaningless to simply state it in english.  Comments before a function need to state the purpose of the function, the details of the parameters and the meaning of the returned value.

Comment: for ease of documenting, declare only one variable per line.  so this line: 'int a[10],i,n;'  would be better written as 3 lines, with each variable declaration followed by a comment about what it is used for

Comment: Did you know there is a `qsort()` function in `stdlib.h`?  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html

Comment: When posting code about a runtime problem.  the posted code should compile, with no warnings/errors nor missing lines (a lot of posters seem to think we can read their minds about what header files to include)

Comment: always check the returned value (not the parameter values) from scanf() (and family of functions) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: _"C code for Quicksort which seems perfectly OK. But the code doesn't works perfectly"_ dafuq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have already indicated in your comments to your code. You need to rethink the partition step for the Quick Sort algorithm - the reason you are encountering an infinite loops is due to the fact that after your swap, `left` and `right` are never updated causing the infinite loop.

This is not of my own but helped me when I was learning about complex sorting algorithms:

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
  int i = left, j = right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
  /* partition */
  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  };
```

You may find this helpful and as many have stated you may need to clean up your code to help with debugging aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Seems  `right++;` should be `right--;`
OR both side are increase.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `quicksort()`

```
quicksort(A,low,pivot);
quicksort(A,pivot,high);
```

These arguments should be like this -

```
quicksort(A,low,pivot-1);  
quicksort(A,pivot+1,high);
```

In function `partition()`

```
     while(A[right]>pivot)
        right++;
```

here in this loop `right` should be decrementated

```
    while(A[right]>pivot)
        right--;
```

And at last the swapping in this function

```
 temp=A[right];
 A[right]=A[left];
 A[left]=temp;
```

But actually `right` should be the last position for pivot

```
 A[left]=A[right]
 A[right]=pivot
```

And just a suggestion please increase the size of your array `a[]` in main function.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems in this code as already pointed out by many commenters, I just thought I would present you an implementation that actually works, including (hopefully) helpful comments about what is done:

```
#include <stdio.h>       
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 16

static void quicksort_rec(int *l, int *r)
{
    int *p, *ll, *rr, t;

    if (r-l < 1) return; /* only one element left -> nothing to sort */

    p = r;      /* use last element for pivot (any element would do) */
    rr = r-1;   /* pointer to last element to compare with pivot */
    ll = l;     /* pointer to first element to compare with pivot */

    while (1)
    {
        /* move ll until we find something greater than pivot on the left */
        while (ll <= rr && *ll <= *p) ++ll;

        /* move rr until we find something smaller than pivot on the right */
        while (ll <= rr && *rr >= *p) --rr;

        /* ll and rr met? then we're done with this step */
        if (rr <= ll)
        {
            /* swap pivot to the "meeting position" */
            t = *p;
            *p = *ll;
            *ll = t;

            /* sort partitions recursively */
            quicksort_rec(l, ll-1);
            quicksort_rec(ll+1, r);

            /* done */
            return;
        }

        /* swap greater element on the left with smaller element on the right */
        t = *rr;
        *rr = *ll;
        *ll = t;
    }
}

static void quicksort(int *v, int num)
{
    quicksort_rec(v, v+num-1);
}


int main()
{
    char buf[64];       /* buffer for user input */
    int *values;        /* pointer to dynamically allocated array */
    int avail;          /* number of currently free slots in the array */
    int entries = 0;    /* number of total entries in the array */
    int i;              /* iterating variable */

    puts("Quicksort Example\n"
         "=================\n"
         "\n"
         "Enter whole numbers to sort, just hitting enter starts sorting.\n");

    /* allocate first chunk of memory */
    values = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    if (!values)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    avail = CHUNK_SIZE;

    while (1)
    {
        fputs("Please enter next number: ", stdout);

        /* try reading user input, if impossible, break */
        if (!fgets(buf, 64, stdin)) break;

        /* if input is empty, break */
        if (buf[0] == '\0' || buf[0] == '\r' || buf[0] == '\n') break;

        /* convert input to integer as next value for array */
        values[entries] = atoi(buf);
        printf("Added `%d' to sort list\n", values[entries]);
        ++entries;

        /* check whether there is space left in the array */
        if (!--avail)
        {
            /* if not, increase array size by the next chunk */
            values = realloc(values, (entries + CHUNK_SIZE) * sizeof(int));
            if (!values)
            {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(1);
            }

            /* reset available slots to size of chunk */
            avail = CHUNK_SIZE;
        }
    }

    printf("Now sorting %d elements with quicksort.\n", entries);

    /* sort the array */
    quicksort(values, entries);

    puts("Result:");

    for (i = 0; i < entries; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", values[i]);
    }

    free(values);
    return 0;
}
```